Docker execution related issue
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build
time="2024-05-07T07:51:43+05:30" level=warning msg="F:\\AuctionEasePlatform\\docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete"
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping, check if the server supports the requested API version

Executing docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build gives the above error

can you show as docker-compose.yml as well as output from: docker compose version. Maybe it gives a clue about the issue. What if you remove version at the top of your yaml file? - as far as I know it isn't necessary in v2.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@macosmi
version: '3'
volumes:
app:
driver: local
services:
frontend:
build: ./frontend/my-app
network_mode: host
ports:
- "3000:3000"
depends_on:
- backend
volumes:
- app:/usr/src/app
- /usr/src/app/node_modules
backend:
build: ./backend
network_mode: host
ports:
- "9002:9002"
environment:
- PORT=9002
- MONGODB_URI=.............
- JWT_SECRET=...............
- CLOUDINARY_URL=....................
volumes:
- app:/usr/src/app
- /usr/src/app/node_modules

@AmantaPhelix - have you tried to remove the first line with 'version: '3' altogether?
